# Doing 2 things at the same time in Java

Tags: java

Well, I'm working on an online game in Java. I have a client and a server. And the speech system waits for a new message to be displayed like this:

```
public void addSpeech(String msg) {
    String newMsg = parsel10n(msg);
    m_narrator.addSpeech(parsel10n(newMsg));
    while (!m_narrator.getCurrentLine().equalsIgnoreCase(newMsg))
      ;
    while (!m_narrator.getAdvancedLine().equalsIgnoreCase(newMsg))
      ;
 }
```

The problem is.. the rest of the application stops because of the while loops. I don't see any other players move or see the chat while in this loop. Is there a way I could run this method without touching the rest of the application (client) with the loops? Should threads be involved? I hope you'd be able to answer me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, threads should be involved.

If you just want to launch a task in parallel of your main execution thread, you might do this :

```
new Thread(){
   public void run(){
        addSpeech();
   }
}.start();
```

But you'll have to check your data structures can be accessed from more than one thread.

And you might want to do something on end of task, etc. So I suggest you look for a tutorial about java threads and task queues.

Comment: Which is faster? Using a daemon thread or creating a new thread each time?

Comment: Threads in java aren't terribly expensive but it's generally better to keep a [queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) of todo task and to keep the same thread (or a pool if really needed).

Comment: What about runnable and timer class? Are they efficient when it needs about 50ms intervals?

Comment: A Runnable costs nothing per se. And a timer is efficient, yes. But do you need to launch something every 50 ms ? Don't forget the core of the task may be heavy.

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204923/log-thread-memory-leak/), OP shows a thread running in the background to empty a queue that other threads can fill (in this case his whole class extends Thread).

Comment: I don't still really understand it completely and this is gonna be so hard to implement but thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

To perform more than one task concurrently, you need to use multiple threads.

In any case it is considered bad practice to do anything but trivial computation or delay on the GUI Thread otherwise it can lock up for periods of time.

Answer (score 0):

Use multi-threading. Look at java.util.concurrent package for more details. You could use observer pattern for signaling and notifications.